# Finding Eigenvalues of First Order ODEs with Periodic BC?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, mathematical-physics, eigenfunctions

Suppose I have the eigenproblem:
$$A(x)\frac{df(x)}{dx} + B(x) f(x) = \lambda f(x), x\in[a,b]$$
$$f(a)=f(b)$$
where $A$, $B$ are some smooth real functions for simplicity. If we would have also an extra $\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}$ and some extra BC condition, this would be a Sturm-Liouville problem and there is a lot of theory on that. But how about this first order problem? At first glance it should be easier to handle, but on a close inspection I found it quite troublesome and I also couldn't find any theory about it so far.

Comment: Integrating directly we have $f(x)=C\exp\left(\int_a^x dx'\frac{\lambda-B(x')}{A(x')} \right)$ with $C=f(a)$. For $f(b)=f(a)=C$ we require $\int_a^b dx'\frac{\lambda-B(x')}{A(x')}=2\pi in$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $A,B,\lambda$ are presumed real, we must have $n=0$. But then we can write $\lambda=\frac{\int B/A}{\int 1/A}$ which has a definite value. So it looks like there is only one eigenfunction with the given boundary conditions

Comment: @Sal I guess I just didn't see this solution because I was tackling it in a too general manner (where you can't divide by $A$). If $A$ has zeros on $[a,b]$, and we can't integrate directly, could there be multiple eigenfunctions?

Comment: In that case it may be difficult to say in general: the uniqueness theorem gives a sufficient (but not necessary) condition on $f'=F(x,f)$. For example, let $f(-1)=f(1)=1$, $A=x$, $B=0$. Then there is a discrete spectrum $f_n(x)=(-x)^{2n}$ with $\lambda=2n$. The same problem with $A=x^2$ has just one eigenfunction, $f=1$ with $\lambda=0$, and with $A=x^3$ we get a continuous spectrum $f_\lambda(x)=\exp((1-x^{-2})\lambda/2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we can try integrating directly (summarizing comments). This yields

$$
f(x)=f(a)\exp \left(\int\limits_a^x dx' \frac{\lambda-B(x')}{A(x')} \right)
$$

The requirement that $f(a)=f(b)$ sets $\int\limits_a^b dx \frac{\lambda-B(x)}{A(x)}=2\pi in$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. If everything is real, and all the integrals exist, then $\lambda=\frac{\int dx \ B/A}{\int dx \ 1/A}$ so that there is just one eigenfunction with this eigenvalue.

To study the problem more generally, let us ask: "*when is there a complete set of eigenfunctions?*". This will be true if the operator is (truly) self-adjoint. Let

$$
L=A(x)\partial_x+B(x)
$$

Define an inner product with real weight $w(x)>0$

$$
\left<v|u\right>=\int\limits_a^b dx \ v^*(x)u(x)w(x)
$$

By direct substitution, we find that for real $A$, there is no weight such that $L$ is even formally self-adjoint. This is a bit of a surprise compared to the second order operators. Let $A$, $B$, and $f$ be complex. We will find conditions on $A$ and $B$ as well as $w$ such that $L$ is self-adjoint.

$$
\left<v|Lu\right>=\int\limits_a^b dx v^*Au'w+\int\limits_a^bv^*Buw
$$

Integrating by parts

$$
\left<v|Lu\right>=v^*Auw \bigg|_a^b+\int\limits_a^b dx \ uw \left[(vB^*)^*-(v'A^*)^*- (vA{^*}')^*-(vA^*w'/w)^*\right]
$$

From the terms in $[...]$ we find the formal adjoint

$$
L^\dagger = B^*-A^*\partial_x-A{^*}'-A^*w'/w \stackrel{?}{=} A \partial_x +B
$$

So we require $-A^*=A$, which means $A$ must be pure imaginary. With this, the other terms read

$$
B^*+A'+Aw'/w=B
$$

This may be solved for $w$

$$
w(x)=K\exp\left(\int\limits^x dx' \ \frac{B(x')-B^*(x')-A'(x')}{A(x')} \right)
$$

With the integration constant $K$ which we may choose. In the special case $B \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $w(x)=\pm i/A(x)$, with sign chosen so $w>0$, which is only possible if $iA$ does not change sign over $a<x<b$. One may object to division by a possibly vanishing $A$ here: but now we can see that if the integral does not exist, or if $K$ cannot be chosen such that $w>0$, then there will be no $w$ such that $L$ is self-adjoint. Now the boundary terms. We require

$$
v^*Auw \bigg|_a^b=0
$$

For $u(a)=u(b)$ and those $v$ such that $v^*(a)=v^*(b)$.

$$
v^*(a)A(a)u(a)w(a)=v^*(b)A(b)u(b)w(b)
$$

For these self-adjoint boundary conditions, none of the terms above may vanish, and we require

$$
A(a)w(a)=A(b)w(b)
$$

This is automatically satisfied in the case $B \in \mathbb{R}$, $w=\pm i/A$, so long as $A$ does not vanish at either $a$ or $b$. I think this is as far as we can go in full generality: we have found conditions on $A$ and $B$ (and consequently $w$) for $L$ to possess a complete set of eigenfunctions.

Comment: In the expression of $w$, when $B\in\mathbb{R}$, we would get $w(x) = K exp(-int^x dx' \frac{A'(x')}{A(x')}$, even if $A$ can be 0 for some $\{x_0^{(n)}\}_n$, if $\lim_{x \to x_0^{(n)}} \frac{A'(x')}{A(x')} = +\infty$, wouldn't it still work, since the exponential itself will converge to 0?

Comment: We also require $w>0$ over $a<x<b$ for the inner product to work, or at least that $w=0$ only at finitely many isolated points